# JQuery Mobile Page Parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Just wondering how can I pass some parameters to the JQuery Mobile page?

for example

```
<div data-role="page-content">                                                      
         <ul class="gallery">   
                    <li><a href="#mypage?01"><img src="1.jpg"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mypage/02"><img src="2.jpg"/></a></li>                           
         </ul>                        
</div><!-- /content -->
```

As you can see, I tried # and ? However they don't work

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by changing the following things.

I. Remove the `<a>`

II. Internal page to external page

```
"#mypage" to "mypage.html"
```

III. Bind "Click" event of image to a function that calls the page

```
$("#img1").click(function () {
      $.mobile.changePage("mypage.html", { data: { [...parameters...] } });
//eg: $.mobile.changePage("mypage.html", { data: { "param1": "value1" } });
});
```

IV. In the MyPage.html use this

```
<div data-role="page" id="newPageId">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#newPageId").on("pageshow", onPageShow);
    function onPageShow(e,data)
    {
        var url = $.url(document.location);

        var param1 = url.param("param1");
        var param2 = url.param("param2");
        :
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

You can follow detailed [Tutorial Here](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/)

You can also view this [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738948/jquery-mobile-change-page) for some variations. *Look at the answer*

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like it's an interesting approach. However we decided to use backbone instead. https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jquerymobile

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage` was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

these are some links that can help you or atleast give you a start

http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/

http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2011/12/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/

[How to pass and get Parameters between two Pages in Jquery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582781/how-to-pass-and-get-parameters-between-two-pages-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is how to deal with parameters when linking to an internal page.

Here is how I solved the problem I was having when I found this question:

```
    <div data-role="page-content">                                                      
      <ul class="gallery">   
        <li><a href="#mypage" data-my_param=1><img src="1.jpg"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#mypage" data-my_param=2><img src="2.jpg"/></a></li>                           
      </ul>                        
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

then...

```
    $('ul').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        myParam = $(this).data('my_param');            
        //do what ever needs to be done to the page with the param
    });
```