# How to change page in jQuery mobile (1.4 beta)?

Tags: jquery, api, jquery-mobile, html

I am reading the docs that `$.mobile.changePage` has been deprecated.

But it doesn't say in favor of what, or what can I use instead.

Is there a new API documentation page for this?

I used to use `$.mobile.changePage("index.html", {reloadPage:true});` but it seems that adding `reloadPage:true` the page breaks

Comment: I've been looking for `.changePage` replacement, but couldn't find it. I assume (_not sure, however tested on 1.4 beta 1_) `$.mobile.navigate()` would be replacing it. It accepts same arguments of `.changePage`.

Comment: The above statement is correct, please go through this documentation http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-beta.1/dist/demos/navigation/

Comment: aha, can someone please post this as an answer so i can check it as correct?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As of **jQuery Mobile 1.4**, `$.mobile.changePage()` is deprecated and replaced with:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "target", { options });
```

*Shortened*...

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "target", { options });
```

*Even shorter*...<sup>(1)</sup>

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "target", { options });
```

**Note:** *target* is #page_id or URL.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yTt9b/)**

---

<sup>(1)</sup> `<body>` is *pageContainer* by default, unless `$.mobile.pageContainer` is modified on `mobileinit`.

Comment: some more info that i found on this: `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer ("change", "index.html", {reloadPage: true});`

Comment: Thank you - yeah that is a HUGE glaring omission from the documents.

Comment: @Omar How to change the external page using pageContainer... Is that possible..?

Comment: @Koushik `window.location.href = "url";` should work in case you're trying to load an external page from a different domain with "access origin" disabled.

Comment: Am I the only one who experiences the problem that the browser does not scroll to the top of the target page using this method (v 1.4.5)?

Comment: By the way: the `reloadPage` option is deprecated, use `reload` instead with the same values (e.g. `{reload:true}`)

Comment: Thanks for the expansion - this is SOOO poorly documented on their website.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', nextPage, {
  transition: 'flow',
  reload    : true
});
```

nextpage: is URL to the nextpage example (var nextPage = 'nextPage.html')

Comment: I know but it dose not work for 100% and about 60% it generates a failure that the pagecontainer is not initialized.