# What to use in place of $.mobile.changePage()?

Tags: jquery-mobile, deprecated

The release notes of [jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 RC1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/10/24/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-rc1-released/) marks `$.mobile.changePage()` as deprecated. Which API method replaces it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change page in latest jquery mobile (1.4 beta)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174611/how-to-change-page-in-latest-jquery-mobile-1-4-beta)

Comment: Thanks. I had searched for this but didn't find it. Voted for close. It doesn't even appear in the related questions list.

Comment: No worries. Because there are few jQM 1.4 related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page", { options });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582457/what-to-use-in-place-of-mobile-changepage)