# JQM pagecontainer error

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using JQM 1.6.4

I am trying to change to another page within the same HTML document by using the call:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#aquire_date");
```

which I found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174611/how-to-change-page-in-latest-jquery-mobile-1-4-beta/).

However, when I try, I get the error:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer is not a function
```

Here is the DIV I am trying to switch to:

```
<div data-role="page" id="#aquire_date">
```

Am I setting the call correctly?

Comment: This function is for JQM 1.4 (latest version). Btw, there's no JQM 1.6.4, you mean jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: Geeze. You are absolutely correct. I got the 2 confused. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To get **jQuery Mobile 1.4** working, you need to at least use **jQuery 1.8.3**. The recommended jQuery library is **1.9**.

- jQM 1.1 -> jQuery 1.6.4
- jQM 1.2 -> jQuery 1.7.2
- jQM 1.3 & 1.4 -> jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Mobile (JQM) added Pagecontainer Widget in 1.4.0 version http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/ so you will have to use 1.4.0 atleast so that you won't get the error
Also it is recommended to use jQuery 1.9.1 or above with it.