# Phonegap white page during page change

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

White page appears during page change using `window.location = "otherpage.html"` and happening only in the mobile but not desktop.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Does the page open in a separate tab on desktop?

Comment: @Deepika of course not

Comment: try this: window.location.href = "otherpage.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have disabled the jquery mobile's ajax loading by using `data-ajax="false"` and directly use `window.location = "otherpage.html"`. This causes the whole page to be fully reloaded and therefore we can see a white screen during loading.

The correct way should be

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "target", { options });
```

Reference:
[How to change page in jQuery mobile (1.4 beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174611/how-to-change-page-in-latest-jquery-mobile-1-4-beta)