# White screen appear when i use window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I used window.location.href when i navigate form one html page to another html page i am   getting white screen and then page 2 will be display.
Following is my code i use html5,jquery mobile,phoneGap

```
 $("#search").on("click", function() {  
            window.location.href='index.html#searchModule';         
        });
```

Comment: I guess it's just a thing the browser does... try with a different browser and tell us if that gets you the same result.

Comment: try window.location.href='index.html';..only

Comment: try a more specific url an absolute or relative one.. that starts with something like `/` or `http://`

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: Do you want to navigate to the other page with or without jQM's Ajax?

Comment: yes i want to navigate other Html page with jQM's

Comment: then use jQM's [change page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174611/how-to-change-page-in-latest-jquery-mobile-1-4-beta/19186330#19186330) function.