# Jquery mobile page change calling multiple times

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am working on Jquery Mobile project.I have three pages called page A,B and C. Page A is my start up page. I am navigating to page B using :

```
  $.mobile.changePage("B.html",{transition:"slide"});
```

and same like page B -> C . There is linking between page C -> A using from page C:

```
  $.mobile.changePage("A.html",{transition:"slide"});
```

First time it is working fine with flow A -> B -> C -> A , But second time when I perform this action then control goes back automatically from 
C -> B . like A -> B -> C -> B . Why is this happening.Is it jquery mobile issue (I am using version 1.4.5).

Comment: See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186330/833188)

Comment: could you please post your button/anchor markup?