# jquery-mobile click button to change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have html page with a few jquery mobile pages as;

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 


<div data-role="page" id="page2">
```

With a click of a button I wanted to use the following code to goto 2nd page from the 1st page.

```
 $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { 
                transition: 'slideup'       
            }

           );
```

But the site http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/ says;

Note: jQuery.mobile.changePage is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Use the pagecontainer widget's change() method instead.

How to use this to change a page on a button click.

Comment: I found this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738948/jquery-mobile-change-page

Answer (score 0):

As said on jquery 1.5 doc you can use this code inside a click event:
`$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page2");`